# How to fix "jquery append something but its javascript functions are not working just on click event of button"

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I append a "multiple tags dropdown" using jQuery on button click event it doesn't append the multiple tags dropdown but the simple drop down(I think I need to reload javascript file after appending).
Because, when I append the same thing on jquery(document).ready(function(){}) it appends the multiple tags dropdown with working javascript functionality.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   //this work perfectly in .ready() function

  $("#parent").append(' <select  class="standardSelect"><option>hello</option><option>hello</option> </select>');

$('#sa').attr('multiple','');




//but on button click event it just append the simple dropdown of html without any javascript functionality of tags.
$( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {



//$("#parent").append(' <select  class="standardSelect"><option>hello</option<option>hello</option> </select>');

)};//click()
)};//ready()
```

Comment: @Speedofround thanks for responding and i have already remove syntax errors but still it doesnt work. actually jquery append the dropdown with its java script functionality i document .ready function but when i does the same thing in button click event it append the simple dropdown without its javascript functionality so kindly tell me how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

It all worked fine once I fixed your syntax errors

```js
jQuery(document).on('change', '.standardSelect', function() {
  console.log('selected ' + jQuery(this).val())
})

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  //this work perfectly in .ready() function
  $("#parent").append(' <select  class="standardSelect"><option>hello</option><option>hello</option> </select>');
  $('#sa').attr('multiple','');

//but on button click event it just append the simple dropdown of html without any javascript functionality of tags.
  $( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {
    $("#parent").append(' <select  class="standardSelect"><option>hello</option><option>hello</option> </select>');
  });//click()
 
                       
});//ready()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  
</div>

<button id="mybutton">Test</button>
```

Heres a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/SpringsTea/pen/GbEOLZ?editors=1011)

To bind event handlers to dynamically create elements, that meaning, elements that did not exist when the document loaded, you need to bind the handler to a parent element:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '.standardSelect', function() {
  console.log('selected ' + jQuery(this).val())
})
```

In this example I used the document it self, which is the parent of everything.

Comment: thanks for responding and i have already remove syntax errors but still it doesnt work. actually jquery append the dropdown with its java script functionality i document .ready function but when i does the same thing in button click event it append the simple dropdown without its javascript functionality so kindly tell me how can i solve this problem – Muhammad Junaid

Comment: @MuhammadJunaid I think I understand your problem, see updated answer. It's hard to tell without seeing how your selectbox logic is setup.

Comment: i think you are mistaken in understandig my problem. actually the problem is i am using some  libraries and i have implemented thier classes in html and they work fine but when i add some elements dynamically even with their classes and ids mentions (means they should also perform the functionalities of libraries and external javascript files) but it implement a simple html element without the implementation of javascript files.

Comment: Sorry but whatever you are describing is not displayed in your question.